# SDL grid color smoothing

Tags: c++, sdl, interpolation

Is it possible to smooth a grid of values displayed as color using methods such as bicubic or linear interpolation with SDL? Currently I use SDL_FillRect to fast fill rectangles. Here is a reference image of interpolation in MATLAB to get an idea of what I want to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in system in SDL to do what you want. You could easily do this using a shader and OpenGL, but you mentioned using `SDL_FillRect` so I assume you are using an `SDL_Surface` which suggests you're not using OpenGL. In that case you can easily plot the pixels and calculate the colours however you like.

Comment: I assume OpenGL would be significantly faster?

Comment: It would be, but depending on your resolution and how interactive you want the program to be it might not be significant or important.